# Assign new data point to cluster in kernel k-means (kernlab package in R)?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, kernlab

I have a question about the `kkmeans` function in the `kernlab` package of R.  I am new to this package and please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here.

I would like to assign a new data point to a cluster in a set of clusters that were created using kernel k-means with the function 'kkmeans'.  With regular clustering, one would do this by calculating the Euclidian distance between the new data point and the cluster centroids, and choose the cluster with the closest centroid.  In kernel k-means, one must do this in the feature space.

Take the example used in the kkmeans description:

```
data(iris)

sc <- kkmeans(as.matrix(iris[,-5]), centers=3)
```

Say that I have a new data point here, which I would like to assign to the closest cluster created above in `sc`.

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width
     5.0         3.6          1.2         0.4
```

Any tips on how to do this? Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Kernel K-means uses the Kernel function to calculate similarity of objects. In the simple k-means you loop through all centroids and select the one which minimizes the distance (under used metric) to the given data point. In case of kernel method (default kernel function in `kkmeans` is `radial basis function`), you simply loop through centroids and select the one that **maximizes the kernel function value** (in case of RBF) or **minimizes the kernel induced distance** (for any kernel). Detailed description of converting kernel to distance measure is provided [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/papers/kerneld/kerneld.pdf) - in general distance induced by kernel `K` can be calculated through `d^2(a,b) = K(a,a)+K(b,b)-2K(a,b)`, but as in case of RBF, `K(x,x)=1` for all `x`, you can just maximize the `K(a,b)` instead of minimizing the whole `K(a,a)+K(b,b)-2K(a,b)`.

To get the kernel function from `kkmeans` object you can use `kernelf` function

```
> data(iris)
> sc <- kkmeans(as.matrix(iris[,-5]), centers=3)
> K = kernelf(sc)
```

So for your example

```
> c=centers(sc)
> x=c(5.0, 3.6, 1.2, 0.4)
> K(x,c[1,])
             [,1]
[1,] 1.303795e-11
> K(x,c[2,])
             [,1]
[1,] 8.038534e-06
> K(x,c[3,])
          [,1]
[1,] 0.8132268
> which.max( c( K(x,c[1,]), K(x,c[2,]), K(x,c[3,]) ) )
[1] 3
```

the closest centroid is `c[3,]=5.032692 3.401923 1.598077 0.3115385` in the sense of used kernel function.

Comment: Should this be consistent with the cluster memberships output of sc[] ?

Comment: Link does not work anymore, it could be great if you could restore it and allow users to further deep dive in such a topic. Thank you very much!