# How to define Kmeans cluster of the new data

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka

Im trying to cluster some data and wanna learn accurancy of it on weka.I mean Lets say, we cluster our training data to n groups but now we have a new test data to learn clusters. How can we do it? I checked the samples but all of them are about to test in training data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign new data point to cluster in kernel k-means (kernlab package in R)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621642/assign-new-data-point-to-cluster-in-kernel-k-means-kernlab-package-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `FilteredClusterer`, and then choose `KMeans` in the Configuration Dialog of the FilteredClusterer.

Here is some text from the "More" button that shows some documentation about this clusterer:

> NAME weka.clusterers.FilteredClusterer
>
> SYNOPSIS Class for running an arbitrary clusterer on data that has
>   been passed through an arbitrary filter. **Like the clusterer, the
>   structure of the filter is based exclusively on the training data**
>   and test instances will be processed by the filter without changing
>   their structure.